# Cocos2d: smooth "fog"/"smoke" animation with few frames, is it possible?

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on the animation of some planets. Each planet has a different fog. 
Each fog correspond to a sequence of 3/4 images that have the same size of the planet (e.g. 100pixels*100pixels).

What I want to achieve is a smooth animation where the fog gradually expands, and then reverses to the original size (e.g. fogA, fogA expands, fogA disappears while fogB is faded in, fogB exapnds, fogB disappears while fogC fadesIn, etc...).

The problem is that It seems that the only way to do so is to have a sprite child for each fog frame (e.g. child for fogA, child for fogB, etc..). Then yes I can apply the ScaleTo action and CCFadeOut/In to each child but there is no way to put those in a CCSequence of actions as CCSequence doesn't accept other CCSequence object as "finite animations". I guess its because CCSequence is not a finite animation.

Would anyone have a good solution for this? 
Here is a representation of a "fog" made by three different images. The idea would be to have the first sprite to gradually expand and then be replaced by the second which as well will gradually expand and finally be replaced by a third sprite which will expand and then start to reverse the cycle (reduce, sprite B starts to reduce to become of initial size and then fades out while sprite A fades in and becomes as of original size - cycle repeats forever).

[image: What I want to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use a particle emitter to do this?

You can change the size and shape of the emitter to increase/decrease the amount of fog.

Change the size of the particles and lifespan/birthrate to increase/decrease the intensity of the fog, etc...

You wouldn't need much movement of the particles, just a slight movement and a fade over time.

Comment: I hadn't found any good particle emitter in the Cocos2d code and I was reluctant of using http://www.71squared.com/en/particledesigner as when I tried I couldn't get the "fog" result.

Comment: I have particleDesigner and it's good but you have to spend a while fiddling to get it right. Once I'd got the effect you just copy paste into CCParticleEmitter and it should be right. It's been a while since I used it though.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was a bit reluctant because I tried the demo version and on the website it says that you can use also "shared" emitters by other users. I couldn't find a link to the shared emitters library (although the dozen of examples that come with the demo version are pretty cool). I will dig into this and follow their tutorial properly. Thanks :)